# Get charset attribute of meta element in (X)HTML document with xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am doing some web scraping stuff with python. But as you know some web pages has different charsets. I need to get those web pages charset. So long story short, for lxml, What is xpath pattern?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value of the `content` attribute of a `meta` element?

Comment: Yes. That's what i am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
/html/head/meta[@http-equiv='Content-Type']/@content
```

HTML5:

```
/html/head/meta/@charset
```